# Array loop of line items in WooCommerce order REST API

Tags: php, arrays, rest, api, woocommerce

I want to loop array of line_items in WooCommerce rest api of orders.

What I came too close is this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-pass-the-line_items-parameter-in-orders-rest-api/

One guy states Line items should be in array(array(item1), array(item2),....) format: item1,item2 increases by selecting multiple items in single orders in WooCommerce rest api.

I have asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557500/creating-order-line-items-dynamically-on-woocommerce-rest-api

I want to dynamically obtain this

```
    $order['line_items'] = array(
   array(
    'product_id' => 93,
    'quantity'   => 2
    ),
    array(
    'product_id' => 22,
    'variation_id' => 23,
    'quantity'   => 1
   ),
);

$results = $client->post( 'orders', $order );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating order Line items dynamically on Woocommerce Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557500/creating-order-line-items-dynamically-on-woocommerce-rest-api)

Comment: you got downvoted because SO is not a free code writing service, you are supposed to show an attempt to solve your problem, or at least if you searched and that you didn't find, why the specific solutions don't fit to your problem. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), reposting won't help

Comment: Creating order Line items dynamically on Woocommerce Rest API This is my own question, And Kaddath I already wrote what I tried in my previous question if you may see it.

Comment: @NischalPrajapati OK i see, that's just not very clear at first glance, with the sentence before people probably think that the whole code is an example from the docs (as i did), and people are quick to vote. What could help us now is you to add why the code you tried didn't fit. Was there any error displayed? is the result not what you expect and how?

Comment: There was no error displayed as I am testing on postman output on json and code works fine for just 1 product item with the code I tried, but I want to make my code work for more than 1 product line item on woocommerce rest api. You can see my previous question I have explained briefly there.